# Несколько вопросов о DTO

Tags: c#, dto

Прочёл несколько статей о DTO. В целом, концепция ясна, уже начал её использовать, но осталось несколько непонятных моментов.

1. Допустимо ли устанавливать значения по умолчанию для полей в классах DTO? Например для условного UserDTO:

```
    public class UserDTO
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = "John";
        public string LastName { get; set; } = "Galt";

        public bool IsMarried { get; set; } = false;
        public int NumberOfChildren { get; set; } = 0;

        public string Citizenship { get; set; } = "U.S.";
        ...
    }
```

2. Обычно пишут, что в DTO не должно быть логики, только свойства. Но ведь свойства и нужны для придания дополнительной логики обычным переменным! То есть в геттеры и сеттеры всё же можно добавлять логику?
3. Что насчёт конструкторов? Их наличие допустимо?
4. Одно из применений для DTO я вижу в упрощении создания объектов. То есть вместо длинных конструкторов с десятком параметров

   ```cs
   public User(string firstName = "John", string lastName = "Galt", 
               bool isMarried = false, int numberOfChildren = 0,
               string Citizenship = "U.S."...
   ```

   принимать и обрабатывать DTO

   ```cs
   public User(UserDTO user)
   ```

   Правильное ли это использование?

Comment: Зависит многое ещё от того, как именно вы эти `DTO` объекты используете, в каком фреймворке и т.д. По идее лучше в `DTO` ничего лишнего не делать, это должны быть полностью прозрачные объекты. Хотите логику, дефолтные значения и прочее - делайте всё это там, где вы из этих `DTO` достаёте данные или кладёте туда данные. Если делать хоть какую-то логику в `DTO`, вы потом замучаетесь отлавливать мелкие глюки и долго будете разбираться, почему из базы вышли одни данные, а в программу пришли другие и наоборот. `DTO` должны быть максимально простыми и прозрачными, как и их предназначение.

Comment: DTO - Data Transfer Object, он нужен только для передачи объекта по сети/etc. А какая логика в DTO вам нужна? В Геттерах и сеттерах никакой логики, обычно, я не видел и не делал (а зачем она там?). Зачем конструкторы DTO, если, как правило, используют мапперы (AutoMapper, Mapster, etc., 4-ый вопрос на этом моменте отпадает тоже).

Comment: `public User(UserDTO user)` - а это плохо, потому что в идеале должен быть `loose coupling`, а вы тут связываете слой доменной модели со слоем БД или где у вас там `DTO` лежат. Да, так проще поначалу, но сложнее в большом проекте. `User` должен инициализироваться простыми данными, а создание `User` из `DTO` должно быть в той части программы, которая знает и про доменную модель и про слой БД, но не в самой доменной модели и не в слое БД.

Comment: Использую DTO в основном для сериализации и передачи между слоями одного приложения. 

Логика — приведение полученной строки к нужному виду, например. Убрать лишние пробелы там, и прочее.

Но ладно логика, без неё действительно можно обойтись. Меня больше интересует именно значения по умолчанию. Порой создаю DTO-объекты в разных местах программы и для разных целей. И в каждом методе, формирующем DTO надо вручную вводить значения по умолчанию? Мне кажется это менее эффективным и более опасным, чем просто установить их в классе DTO, разве нет?

Comment: А не надо в разных местах, надо в одном )  Для этого делается, например, слой "репозиторий" и он уже работает с БД. Вот в нём и надо создавать объекты `DTO`, наружу выставлять методы, которые это делают и дёргать эти методы в тех местах программы, в каких нужно. Хотя вообще непонятно, зачем вам объекты `DTO` где-то, кроме собственно слоя "репозиторий". Ну или какой слой у вас эти дто отправляет куда-то и принимает откуда-то. Дальше уже объекты доменной модели должны ходить. Повторюсь - дто не должны выполнять никакие другие функции, кроме передаточной.

Comment: И да, избегайте дефолтных параметров и значений по умолчанию. Это удобно, но не прозрачно, дальше из-за этого могут быть проблемы. Грубо говоря, должен быть метод, принимающий все поля дто для создания дто. И должны быть такие же методы с урезанным числом параметров, в явном виде вызывающие из себя тот полный метод с нужными параметрами. Да, это больше методов, но зато так нельзя будет ничего сломать, просто забыв в очередной раз при вызове одного мега-метода с дефолтами указать один из параметров.

Comment: @CrazyElf > Хотя вообще непонятно, зачем вам объекты DTO где-то, кроме собственно слоя "репозиторий". << К примеру, редактирование существующего объекта. Пользовать во View вводит новые данные; ViewModel на основе этих и изначальных данных создаёт объект DTO (урезанная копия полноценного объекта, состоящая исключительно из предназначенных для редактирования полей) и передаёт userDTO в User.Update(userDTO); этот метод в Model обрабатывает DTO и изменяет исходный объект (сам себя) в соответствии с полученными изменениями.

Так нельзя и есть вариант лучше?

Comment: @Kram Вопрос интересный. Зависит опять же от того, кто и как у вас эти `DTO` дальше обрабатывает. Вообще говоря, изменение копии объекта в памяти чревато тем, что кто-то ещё в это время поменяет объект в базе или куда он там передаётся и у вас будет "race condition" с неизвестным финалом. Полноценные фреймворки поддерживают транзакции, следят за своим кэшем, актуален ли он и т.д. При работе с БД всё-таки обычно объект ещё раз читается из бд, меняются нужные поля, и после этого объект скидывается обратно в базу. Вы всё время норовите использовать `DTO` не для того, для чего они предназначены.

Answer (score 1):

1. Допустимо, однако тут есть тонкая грань. К примеру для какого-нибудь dto который потом заммапится для создания сущности (dto -> entity) не надо указывать значения по умолчанию, лучше в методе после маппинга задать значения по умолчанию свойствам сущности (очень хорошо подходит для этого `Fluent Builder`). Например:

```
public class PagedAndSortedRequestDto
{
   public int MaxResultCount { get; set; } = 10;
   public int SkipCount { get; set; }
   public string Sorting { get; set; }
}
```

Тут вполне нормально установить дефолтное значение для `MaxResultCount`, но недопустимо для `SkipCount` и `Sorting`.

2. В DTO не должно быть никакой логики. DTO это просто класс-обёртка для передачи данных
3. Да, допустимо, но делайте конструктор по-умолчанию (если объект подразумевает создание его каким-нибудь AutoMapper)
4. DTO не предназначено для доменных сущностей, это абсолютно разные слои

Comment: Спасибо. Темы мэппинга пока не касался (пишу приложение на WPF), так что некоторые моменты сложно понять. Можете более развёрнуто объяснить чем MaxResultCount принципиально отличается от остальных свойств, почему только ему можно устанавливать значение по умолчанию?

Comment: @Kram это называется пагинация, можете погуглить, очень простая тема, где удобно использовать подобные dto